# How to plot a line on a scatterplot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a line on a scatterplot , but instead I am just getting a scatterplot.
If i remove the scatterplot code the Black line I was trying to get appears fine. is there anything I am missing ?

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

```
df=pd.read_csv("houses_data.csv")

x_values=df["sqft_living"].values
y_values=df["price"].values

x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[1,2,3,4]

# THIS LINE DOESNT APPEAR
plt.plot(x,y,color="black")

plt.scatter(x_values,y_values,alpha=0.6,edgecolors="red",color="blue",marker='o')
plt.xlabel("House Living size (sqft)")
plt.ylabel("Price (1 unit = 100000)")
plt.title("House prices in USA")
plt.show()
```

What I want is a scatterplot with a single line passing through 2 points

[image]

What I am getting is just a scatterplot:
[image]

Comment: If these are your actual `x, y` values in the range of 1 to 4, you won't see this line on scales of 14,000 and 800,000, let alone if it is covered by scatter point markers.

Comment: Try `plt.plot(x,y,color="black", zorder=100)`, the line will be plotted on top.

Comment: `plt.plot([0, x_values.max()], [0, y_values.max()])` would draw a line from `0,0` till the maximum values.  If you want some kind of average line, you could try something like `slope = (y_values / x_values).mean()` and `plt.plot([0, x_values.max()], [0, slope*x_values.max()])`.